# is atomic boolean only useful inside of a loop?

Tags: boolean, atomic

I have a friend who says, the use of `AtomicBoolean` for synchronization of startup / shutdown as follows is ineffective:

```
 public void startup() {
    if (started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                 ... startup code
         }
 }
```

He says `AtomicBoolean` needs to be inside of a loop to be threadsafe. Why can't I use `AtomicBoolean` outside of a loop? What is the rationale behind this?

needs an

Comment: your friend isn't correct

Comment: Have you tried to confirm by some googling whether you friend is correct or not?

Comment: From what I've read the code above is correct, but I respect my friends judgement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AtomicBoolean - A boolean value that may be updated atomically. See
>   the java.util.concurrent.atomic package specification for description
>   of the properties of atomic variables. An AtomicBoolean is used in
>   applications such as atomically updated flags, and cannot be used as a
>   replacement for a Boolean.

by no way it is efficient only in loop, it is efficient when you **need** to change it atomically, for example for locks. got nothing to do with loops

Comment: are you saying the usage scenario above is correct? If the startup method is called at the same time by two different threads, only one thread will execute the startup code?

Comment: well, yeah, but only if they check the same 'started'. make sure it's not a simple member cus' then it will be meaningless @Jamie

Comment: @Jamie: The usage in your question should work fine.  Atomic values use a native compare-and-swap instruction (or some thread-safe emulation thereof, if absolutely necessary), which does both operations effectively simultaneously, so there's no time gap between the compare and the set.  If the compare succeeds, the swap will happen at the same time, before any other thread sees that it's set.

Comment: I wonder what he was referring to then... I'll ask him to chime in and provide his input.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to provide some more context.  For example, if your startup code initializes some state and threads that fail the compare and swap then try to use that state, then you could have a race.  Nothing is forcing the other threads to wait until the initialization is finished.

Comment: True enough...but a loop wouldn't fix any of that.  That'd be a case where full synchronization would be a better idea.

Comment: Yeah, but you'd need a loop to wait for the initialization to finish.  But without more context, I don't we can say anything for sure.